# Is there a way to tell gcc not to substitute typedef names and default parameters when reporting errors?

Tags: c++, gcc, compiler-errors

For example this code:

```
#include <vector>

template<typename T>
void useVector(T);

using thing = std::vector<int>;

int main()
{
    std::vector<thing> vec;
    useVector(vec);
    return 0;
}
```

Produces the overly verbose message:

```
/home/martin/Projects/TestGrounds/main.cpp:11: error: undefined reference to 
`void useVector<std::vector<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >, 
std::allocator<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > > > 
>(std::vector<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >, 
std::allocator<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > > >)'
```

Is there some way to suppress the compiler from **substituting all the typedefs and default parameters** and produce something like:

```
/home/martin/Projects/TestGrounds/main.cpp:11: error: undefined reference to 
void useVector(std::vector<thing>);
```

?

Comment: Give STLFilt [http://www.bdsoft.com/tools/stlfilt.html] or gccfilter [http://www.mixtion.org/gccfilter/] a try. (haven't use either in a while so am not sure what state they're in, hence this is a comment).

Comment: This error message is coming from the linker, not the compiler. That makes it **much** harder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested by Eugen Constantin Dinca, I tried [gccfilter](http://www.mixtion.org/gccfilter/).

The output error is reduced to:

```
/tmp/ccEixtdl.o: In function `main':
test.cpp:(.text+0x30): undefined reference to `void useVector<>(std::vector<>)'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Which is a **huge** improvement.

---

At first you need to download the [gccfilter perl script](http://www.mixtion.org/gccfilter/gccfilter) and place it in your $PATH. Then, you have to install the mentioned Perl modules. Under Ubuntu I just did:

```
cpan App::cpanminus
cpanm Term::ANSIColor
cpanm Getopt::ArgvFile
cpanm Getopt::Long
cpanm Regexp::Common
```

You can test the script by saving the source code from the original question as `test.cpp` and run:

```
gccfilter --colorize --remove-template-args g++ -std=c++11 test.cpp
```

If you are using a linker, you have to run the linker using:

```
gccfilter --colorize --remove-template-args g++
```

as well. If you are using `qmake`, you can add:

```
QMAKE_CXX="gccfilter -c -a g++"
QMAKE_LINK="gccfilter -c -a g++"
```

to your `.pro` file. For QtCreator, this will break the viewing of error messages in the **Issues** tab, but you can view the formatted and simplified error messages in the **Compile Output** tab.